# Facebook Comments plugin - How to remove the option "Comment using"

Tags: facebook, facebook-social-plugins

If the user has not logged into facebook, the comments plugin provides an option to login using Facebook/Yahoo/AOL etc. Is there a way to disable this option and allow only Facebook Authorization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're the admin of the comments block there should be a "settings" link on it. Click this and there should be an option of enabling 3rd party providers

source : https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/490/

Comment: Kewl, Learning new stuff!  Thanks for the heads up on that.